# Conexão Banco de Dados MySQL Local e Servidor Online

Tags: java, mysql, aplicação-web

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação utilizando Java Swing + banco de dados MySQL, porém estou em analise de fazer uma plataforma online que conversa com a aplicação local, utilizando o banco de dados para interligar os dados, pois na realidade o sistema em si não conversaram e sim os bancos.

Gostaria de saber se o MySQL possui tal função e o que devo procurar para poder fazer esta interação, também gostaria de saber se é mais comum e mais correto fazer utilizando a comunicação entre bancos ou fazer entre sistemas mesmo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O que você deseja é o recurso de `Federated tables` do MySQL.
Esse recurso está diponível a partir do MySQL 5.

Com ele é possível interligar dois bancos de dados MySQL diferentes da seguinte forma:

Crie a tabela remota

```
CREATE TABLE test_table (
    id     INT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name   VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    other  INT(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY  (id),
    INDEX name (name),
    INDEX other_key (other)
)
ENGINE=MyISAM
```

E no banco local, recrie a mesma estrutura de tabelas, alterando a `Engine` para `Federated` e inserindo o caminho do banco remoto em `Connection`

```
CREATE TABLE federated_table (
    id     INT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name   VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    other  INT(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY  (id),
    INDEX name (name),
    INDEX other_key (other)
)
ENGINE=FEDERATED
CONNECTION='mysql://fed_user@remote_host:9306/federated/test_table';
```

Como alternativa para a string de conexão do `Connection`, é possível criar um apelido para esse servidor através do comando `CREATE SERVER`:

```
CREATE SERVER remote
FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER mysql
OPTIONS (USER 'Remote', HOST '192.168.1.106', DATABASE 'test');

CREATE TABLE federated_table (
    id     INT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name   VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    other  INT(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY  (id),
    INDEX name (name),
    INDEX other_key (other)
)
ENGINE=FEDERATED
CONNECTION='remote';
```

**Referências**

[How to Use FEDERATED Tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/federated-use.html)

[CREATE SERVER Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-server.html)

Comment: No caso esta tabela que estará como FEDERATED ela só fará uso da tabela que ela se espelha online? Ou posso manejar ela tanto local quanto web que ela se  auto carrega conforme trabalho tanto em quanto na outra.

Comment: Boa pergunta, não sei qual o comportamento dessas tabelas quando não há conexão com a base remota

Comment: Melhor situação seria fazer um teste nestas funções. Muito obrigado.

Comment: @ClaytonQuintiliano segue um case de como configurar um federated com failover http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/onlamp/2006/04/20/advanced-mysql-replication.html?page=4

Comment: Obrigado @gmsantos.