# Visualizar dados de banco Oracle via MySQL

Tags: mysql, oracle

Preciso saber como faço para ter os dados de um banco de dados Oracle em meu banco MySQL, uma espécie de *view*.

Não desejo fazer `insert`, `update` nem `delete` no banco Oracle, preciso apenas um `select` desses dados, para ter eles em minha base MySQL.

Encontrei dois caminhos, os quais não tenho certeza se funcionam:

1) Tenho o ODBC do Oracle instalado em meu servidor que tem MySQL, porém não sei fazer o MySQL "ver" esse meu ODBC para criar um *link* entre as bases de dados.

2) Encontrei o que parece ser um bom caminho para solucionar o problema: http://ftp.nchu.edu.tw/MySQL/tech-resources/articles/dbixmyserver.html

O tutorial referencia a utilização de um servidor de Proxy, o qual torna-se o intermediário entre banco MySQL e outros bancos. Este intermediário é quem permite que uma base de dados possa dar um SELECT na outra base.

Acredito que a solução disposta no item 2 realmente funciona, porém, não tenho conhecimentos em desenvolvimento Perl e não sei como fazer a configuração de proxy requerida para dar certo.

Comment: Sua pergunta não faz sentido, um SGBD não tem como se comunicar com outro SGBD. O mais próximo que está do que você pretende é fazer uma cópia exata de um banco para outro, mesmo que sejam de SGBDs diferentes.

Comment: Não, eu não quero uma cópia estática. Eu quero uma tabela ou view que me permita ver no MySQL os mesmos dados do Oracle, mesmo que este sofra alteração.

Comment: Uma view é uma forma de visualização dos dados dentro de um SGBD, não funciona para ver dados de outro SGBD. Por que você quer visualizar os dados do Oracle no MySQL, afinal de contas?

Comment: Tenho os dados que preciso para uma aplicação web em um banco Oracle (sendo que os dados mudam nesta base de dados). Porém, minha aplicação web utiliza MySQL.

Comment: Então você precisa criar duas conexões – uma MySQL e outra Oracle –, puxar os dados de ambos os bancos e trabalhar com eles na sua aplicação.

Comment: Então, o fato é que desejo que minha aplicação faça consultas apenas no MySQL. Por isso preciso dos dados lá.

Comment: Então crie uma rotina para replicar os dados do Oracle no MySQL. Mas nada do que você quer será possível se em nenhum momento você conectar com o Oracle.

Comment: Então, de Oracle para Oracle existem conexões ODBC. Gostaria de fazer a mesma coisa, porém de Oracle para MySQL.

Comment: Não, não existe a mesma coisa de Oracle para MySQL.

Comment: A única maneira seria criar uma trigger no Oracle mesmo?

Comment: Se a aplicação for "Web" (um aplicativo se comunicando com um servidor, ou um servidor se comunicando com outro servidor) a única maneira que vejo de fazer tal processo é criar um "WebService" (por exemplo um json) que migraria os dados conforme a necessidade, a estrutura do WebService vai ter que funcionar equivalente a um MODEL e usar requisições HTTP para receber os comandos.

Comment: Pois é, mas de Oracle para MySQL eu consigo fazer. Ou seja, eu consigo através do Oracle ver tabelas que tenho no MySQL através do Connector ODBC MySQL.

Comment: @RodrigoRigotti o que ele deseja existe sim, é um recurso chamado Database Link (Oracle) ou Linked Server (SQL Server). Para desenvolvimento web realmente não faz muito sentido ter mais de um DB conversando com outro, mas em outros caso é completamente possível.

Comment: @João uma opção poderia ser o [federated engine](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/31212/conex%C3%A3o-banco-de-dados-mysql-local-e-servidor-online/31218#31218), porém não irá te atender pois só funciona entre mysql-mysql

Comment: @gmsantos legal saber disso, não conhecia mesmo. :)

Comment: Talvez uma comunicação via XML o BD Oracle salva um xml que o MySql lê , resta saber o quão dinâmico é o BD origem , link direto confesso que nunca ouvi falar.

Answer (score 3):

Eu só utilizei ao contrário, fazendo o oracle acessar as tabelas no mysql através de um DBLINK [https://hs2n.wordpress.com/2012/04/03/oracle-create-database-link-to-mysql-database/]

Não seria melhor você fazer isto? De acordo com o que muda no oracle, você por dentro do oracle atualiza no mysql.

Nunca configurei, mais para acessar um dblink vc vai acessar assim: tabela@nomeDbLink, no caso se tiver um dblink configurado no oracle para o mysql, você já consegue acessar as tabelas.

Acessando: [https://community.oracle.com/thread/2273134]

Answer (score 0):

É possível utlizando Federated Tables via Perl DBIx::MyServer proxy

- [referência](http://search.cpan.org/~philips/DBIx-MyServer-0.42/lib/DBIx/MyServer.pm)
- [download](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/dbi.html)

O link que você mandou (que citei como referência) coincidentemente é a melhor referência que existe para se fazer isso, então a melhor opção e estudar mesmo

Answer (score -1):

```
$ora_user = "usuario";
$ora_senha = "senha";
$ora_bd = "(DESCRIPTION=
      (ADDRESS_LIST=
        (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)
          (HOST=192.168.xxx.xxx)(PORT=1521)
        )
      )
      (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=yyyyy))
 )";

if ($ora_conexao = oci_connect($ora_user,$ora_senha, $ora_bd)){
    echo 'Conexão bem sucedida';
}else{
    echo 'Conexão falhada';
}
```

***select***

```
$stid = oci_parse($ora_conexao, 'SELECT A.MATRICULA, 
A.NOME_FUNCIONARIO, A.APELIDO FROM VIEW_X A');
oci_execute($stid);


while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
    //echo ....
}
```